# Lua socket example, trying different sites

Tags: lua

I am using this example. It prints the text based on this site http://www.google.com/robots.txt

```
local socket = require("socket")
client = socket.connect("google.com", 80)
client:send("GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
while true do
  s, status, partial = client:receive(1024)
  print(s or partial)
  if status == "closed" then 
    break 
  end
end
client:close()
```

I use:

```
local socket = require("socket")
client = socket.connect("www.lua.org", 80)
client:send("GET /pil/9.4.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
while true do
  s, status, partial = client:receive(1024)
  print(s or partial)
  if status == "closed" then 
    break 
  end
end
client:close()
```

But, as above, I try with this link, http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html and it doesn't work, saying "HTTP/1.0 302 Moved temporarily". Did same on many other sites, got similar results. Why is that so? Thanks a lot

Comment: Show the code you tried that didn't work as well as the code that did.

Comment: The first code works. But when I replace the "google.com" in the second line with "lua.org" and "/robots.txt" with "/pil/9.4.html" in the third, it doesn't, printing HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily

Comment: Show the *complete* code that doesn't work. Make it a function if needed and call it multiple times for different URLs to show where it fails.

Comment: You need to provide an appropriate `Host:` header on the requests to `lua.org.

Comment: um like what? But I give the correct url at Host:

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving a redirect (HTTP 302 code) which should be handled by issuing a new request to the specified `Location`.

Rather than using raw sockets, you could use the high level [HTTP](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) module from the socket library, which provides a `request` method able to authomatically follow redirects.